isPrime in ASM is always giving the same output
I've been trying to learn ASM and this is one of the problems I've been trying to solve.
The goal of the algorithm is to check if a number is prime. From what I could follow in my head this should work. However it does not. I get the same output regardless of the input. Had this been in any other language, I would have added PRINT statements everywhere to debug, however I can't do that. Is anyone able to provide insight on why this might not work ?
section .data
    number db 15 ; 
    answer db 1 ; 1 -> prime, 0 -> not prime
    prime_msg db 'Number is prime', 0x0a
    not_prime_msg db 'Number is NOT prime', 0x0a
    
    section .bss
    divisor resb 1 ; Reserve one byte for the divisor
    
    section .text
    global _start
    
    _start: 
        mov al, [number]
        mov bl, 2 ; divisor = 2
    
    while_loop:
        cmp bl, al
        jg end  ;if number (al) is < divisor(bl) jump to end
        
        mov dl, al ; Move number into DL
        mov al, bl ; Move divisor into AL
         
        xor ah, ah ;clear remainder
        div bl     ;div al by bl(divisor)
        
        cmp ah, 0  ;compare remainder to 0
        je not_prime ;jump to not_prime if 0
        
        inc bl 
        jmp while_loop
        
    not_prime:
        mov byte [answer], 0
        
    out_not:
        mov edx, 16 ; Length of prime_msg ('Number is prime\n')
        mov ecx, prime_msg ; Pointer to prime_msg
        mov ebx, 1 ; File descriptor for stdout
        mov eax, 4 ; sys_write system call
        int 0x80 ; Make the system call
    
        ; Exit the program
        mov eax, 1 ; sys_exit system call
        xor ebx, ebx ; Return code 0
        int 0x80 ; Make the system call
        
    out_prime:
        mov edx, 20 ; Length of not_prime_msg
        mov ecx, not_prime_msg ; Pointer to not_prime_msg
        mov ebx, 1 ; File descriptor for stdout
        mov eax, 4 ; sys_write system call
        int 0x80 ; Make the system call
    
        ; Exit the program
        mov eax, 1 ; sys_exit system call
        xor ebx, ebx ; Return code 0
        int 0x80 ; Make the system call
        
    end:
        cmp byte[answer], 0 
        je out_not ;if answer = 0 -> not prime
        
        jmp out_prime ;else prime

I tried to change the condition for the loop but it has not helped. I've only managed to change which output is given, but it is still the same regardless of the input.

"print-based debugging" aside, you can still debug assembly code by running it in a debugger.

div bl overwrites al. You should move the mov al, [number] into the while_loop. Also your mov dl, al ; mov al, bl make no sense. dl isn't even used by div bl and bl is the divisor.


it is still the same regardless of the input.

You are erroneously dividing BL by BL, always resulting in quotient=1 and  remainder=0.
Move the number in DL:
    mov   dl, [number]
    mov   bl, 2           ; divisor = 2
while_loop:
    cmp   bl, dl
    jg    end
    
    movzx ax, dl          ; Move NUMBER into AX
    div   bl              ; Div AX by BL
    test  ah, ah          ; Compare remainder to 0
    jz    not_prime
    inc   bl 
    jmp   while_loop

For more info about testing for prime numbers, read this other answer of mine. It contains an optimized solution as well.
